# iOS : How to get data from soap response?

Tags: ios, soap, response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><IOSAPIProjectResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <IOSAPIProjectResult>{"result":[{"projectcatname":"Test1","projectname":"Sample1","imgname":"http://someurl.com/UploadImages/projects/5.jpg"},{"projectcatname":"Test2","projectname":"Sample2","imgname":"http://someurl.com/UploadImages/projects/6.jpg"}],"status":"SUCCESS"}
    </IOSAPIProjectResult></IOSAPIProjectResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I'm getting the following response from an .asmx API, how do I get result from the response?

Answer (score 0):

This is a XML result, use NSXMLParser, the main methods you should use are:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

To check the current element:

`-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;`

To get the string from this element:

`-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;`

Comment: That return the element, when you reach the JSON, parse with JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting your response encoded in JSON. iOS has built in JSON decoding capabilities. I recommend reading the [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

In short, you can get a `NSDictionary` object from JSON encoded data using:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
options:kNilOptions 
error:&error];
```

And then use the `NSDicitionary` object to get the result you are looking for with `objectForKey`.

Comment: When I first saw your question it only showed de JSON part of the response. Now it appears to be wrapped in a XML SOAP Response, so you would have to parse that first.

As Nekak sugests, you should first parse the XML Response, and then get the specific parts of the result that you need by using de JSON serializer.